# Using Dockerfile, why are the contents of the host directory not overwriting the container working directory?

Tags: node.js, docker, npm, dockerfile, alpine-linux

I have the following excerpt from my Dockerfile:

```
# build environment
FROM node:16.3.0-alpine as builder
WORKDIR /app
ENV PATH /app/node_modules/.bin:$PATH
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts -g --silent
COPY . ./
RUN npm run build
```

I'm having some issues understanding a few key parts related to the `COPY` and `RUN` commands.

This seems to be very straight forward, unless I'm just misunderstanding how the commands work. Copy `package.json` and `package-lock.json` to the working directory. Then do a clean install. This would generate the `node_modules` directory in the working directory of the container.

```
COPY package.json ./
COPY package-lock.json ./
RUN npm ci --silent
RUN npm install react-scripts -g --silent
```

However, the next execution is `COPY . ./`. Won't this overwrite the working directory's new `node_modules` folder `node_modules` also exists in the host directory?

Comment: Use .dockerignore file to skip the node_modules folder from docker's build context. Add a line like this to .dockerignore file: `**/node_modules/`

Comment: I forgot all about .dockerignore. Thanks!